# Hide / Show column based on another column choice

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have a list for our helpdesk that has a column "Subject" and a column "Computer Issue". Our helpdesk team wants to hide the "Computer Issue" column from the new form unless the option "Computer" is selected from the "Subject" drop down. The code I am using is hiding the field as intended but when "Computer" is selected from the "Subject" column the "Computer Issue" column is not appearing.
My Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('nobr:contains("Computer Issue")').closest('tr').hide();  
    //Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection 
   $("select[title='Subject']").change(function() {
 if ($("select[title='Subject']").val() != "Computer") 
   {
     $('nobr:contains("Computer Issue")').closest('tr').show();
   } 
 else 
   {
     $('nobr:contains("Computer Issue")').closest('tr').hide();
   }
   });
});
</script>
```

I pulled the code from another question on this site that marked it as the answer and modified it to fit my list but cannot get the column to appear. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, You need to show the `Computer Issue` if the `Computer` is selected, but the above code will show it only if it was not equal to **!=** `Computer`.

So, you just need to swap it from show to hide if it's not equal to `Computer` as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('nobr:contains("Computer Issue")').closest('tr').hide();  
    //Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection 
   $("select[title='Subject']").change(function() {
 if ($("select[title='Subject']").val() != "Computer") 
   {
     $('nobr:contains("Computer Issue")').closest('tr').hide();
   } 
 else 
   {
     $('nobr:contains("Computer Issue")').closest('tr').show();
   }
   });
});
</script>
```

or, just change `!=` to `==` as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('nobr:contains("Computer Issue")').closest('tr').hide();  
        //Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection 
       $("select[title='Subject']").change(function() {
     if ($("select[title='Subject']").val() == "Computer") 
       {
         $('nobr:contains("Computer Issue")').closest('tr').show();
       } 
     else 
       {
         $('nobr:contains("Computer Issue")').closest('tr').hide();
       }
       });
    });
    </script>
```

**Read also**

- [Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using JQuery in SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)
- [Show Hide fields based on dropdown selection SharePoint 2013 / 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Mohamed. It was your script that I used from a previous question. I made the change from != to == and it still is not working. I created a test list using your fields from your example and it worked fine. Unfortunately I think this is more rooted with an issue with my list than with the script. I am going to dig a little deeper.

Comment: You are welcome :) and thanks for your feedback, and please don't hesitate to ask us for any kind of clarification you will need ♥

Comment: Mohamed, I figured out why it was not working. My first field "Subject" was set as a required field. When I set it to optional in my content type it started working as intended. Do you know of a way to make this work if your first column needs to be required? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Chris, could you please try this $("select[title^='Subject']") for the required field but make sure there is no additional field contains subject work

Comment: Good Morning Mohamed, that solved the required field request. Thank you so very much for your assistance!